# Thunderbird Lightning: How to edit categories?

Tags: 18.04, thunderbird, lightning

To edit the categories in the thunderbird lightning calendar could go to `Tools -> Options -> Lightning -> Categories`, but in the current version (`60.3`) this doesn't seem to be possible anymore as `Tools -> Options` was removed. I also couldn't find it under the Preferences.

How is it currently possible to edit the calendar categories (delete, change color etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more recent versions of Thunderbird, the settings for the calendar categories can be found under Edit- Preferences, Calendar tab, Categories. The settings may also be reached from Tools - Add-on preferences - Lightning.

[image: Screenshot of preferences dialog]

(with thanks to flawr for the screenshot!)

Comment: @flawr I don't have tabs either! Thanks for the screen shot.